# Can we use electron functions within external web app?

Tags: angular, electron

Scenario

1. We are loading the external web by using this
   `mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:4200');`
2. This is a separate angular app actually.
3. We are hosting the angular app in the electron app.
4. The angular app working great when sitting in electron app.

Question

1. Can we use the electron function in the external web? Something like we do in electron app.
   `const { shell } = require('electron');`
   `shell.openExternal('file://D:/test.docx');`
   `const SerialPort = require('serialport');`
2. If we do can, what is the syntax for TypeScript?

I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375011/is-it-possible-to-use-electron-in-web-application-loaded-from-external-web-serve) but without confirmed answer. I just like to be sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is an angular wrapper that provides Electron APIs in the renderer process, called `ngx-electron` ( for sure other similar modules are available ). You can access it [here](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron).

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. Will give it a try and get back to you with the result.

Comment: I tried this and got the error message when my angular app compiled by Webpack. Do you mean load this Angular app into Electron by using 'file://${__dirname}/index.html'? My question is loading it by 'http://127.0.0.1:4200'. ERROR in node_modules/ngx-electron/src/electronService.d.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'electron'.

Comment: You wanna use it on the electron app that hosted by electron? using on regular browsers ( like a website )?